# How to make listview item day, start time & end time when user select?

Tags: java, android, datetime, listview

I'm currently working on lecturer appointment system.
So now I'm facing a problem is that how to make a simple weekday, start time & end time for user select, and can add item to list. For my understanding, weekday can use spinner and start time & end time can be use time picker, but I'm stuck on add list item.

Here is my code:
**time_box.xml**

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/day_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            android:entries="@array/days"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/start_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="10:00"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text=" - "
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/end_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="13:30"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

***activity_main.xml***

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="@string/lblBtnAdd"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtItem"
        />
    <include layout="@layout/time_box"
        android:id="@+id/txtItem"
        />
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtItem"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtItem"
        android:text="@string/txtEmpty"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

***MainActivity.java***

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.view.View.*;

/** Note that here we are inheriting ListActivity class instead of Activity class **/
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    /**
     * Items entered by the user is stored in this ArrayList variable
     */
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String> ();

    /**
     * Declaring an ArrayAdapter to set items to ListView
     */
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);

        /** Setting a custom layout for the list activity */
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);

        /** Reference to the button of the layout main.xml */
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btnAdd);

        /** Defining the ArrayAdapter to set items to ListView */
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

        /** Defining a click event listener for the button "Add" */
        OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {
                EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.txtItem);
                list.add (edit.getText ().toString ());
                edit.setText ("");
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();
            }
        };

        /** Setting the event listener for the add button */
        btn.setOnClickListener (listener);

        /** Setting the adapter to the ListView */
        setListAdapter (adapter);
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlB9v.png

The MainActivity I leave it as the original workable code (user input text for adding item to list).

Appreciated who those answer my question, thank you.

Comment: There isn't a question here, strictly speaking. You say are stuck - what specifically you are stuck on?

Comment: The stuck meaning is that I do not have any idea on the next step that adding the user selected "day, start time & end time" item to the list.

Comment: Why is your list of appointments an `ArrayList<String>`? Haven’t you got a `LecturerAppointment` class (maybe by some other name)? And shouldn’t instances of such a class go into your list?

Comment: What I should mention is, I'm doing lecturer appointment system, now lecturer need to insert their available timeslot in lecturer profile. So, list view is the better choice for insert. Currently here (The code above) I using the new project to demo the available time slot list and not influence the original one that I done before. So the LecturerAppointment class does not necessary in this case.

Comment: So what I'm stuck is, how to design let user pick the "day, start time & end time" and add the item to the list.